# where does the android application framework library is included?

Tags: android

android application framework library, is it inside the DEX file or inside of Android OS run time core library? please help...

Comment: in run time where is the app framework libraries I use are located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framework libraries on device are usually found in `/system/framework`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! also when an .apk file is decompiled am I able to get the framework libraries used? please help

Comment: Decompiled code will have references to other classes and these references can be resolved with the framework libs in class loader path.

Comment: so its just references which then resolved to framework libs, thanks laalto.